# select Count(*) database(sql) calling C# using jquery to "class" in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have the following ASP.NET code:

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="Home" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content" runat="Server">
    <div class="row tile_count">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
            <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Total Device</span>
            <div class="count">0</div>
</div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

and this is C# code

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string GetCustomers()
    {
        string query = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Devices";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DbConnect.ConnectStr))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    sda.Fill(ds);
                    return ds.GetXml();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to display the Total Device on the `<div class="count"> </div>` using jQuery. I need help. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know `GetXml()` give you an xml of your query result,
if you have query like`SELECT Count(*) FROM Devices` the you will get something like:

```
 <NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <Column1>447</Column1>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

so in JavasCript by JQuery ajax you can get that xml like:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "GetCustomers",
        dataType: "xml",
        async: false,
        success: function (xml) {
             xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
             $xml = $(xmlDoc),
             $count = $xml.find( "Column1" );
             var countText = $count.text();
             $(".count").html(countText);
        }
    });
```

Note :

1- It is better to use `$.parseXML(xml)` to parse your xml

2- That `ajax` is not tested.(Jsut I want give you the clue)

3- The `url` of ajax must be set true.

if you change the back-end code like:

```
string query = "SELECT Count(*) as Count FROM Devices";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DbConnect.ConnectStr))
{
    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
        {
            sda.Fill(ds);  
            var count = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Count"].ToString();
            var data = new { Count = count };
            return (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(data);  
        }
    }
}
```

then in client-side you can do something easy like if return JSON:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "GetCustomers",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
        async: false,
        success: function (response) {
            var result = JSON.parse(response.d);
            var count = result.Count;
            $(".count").html(count);
        }
    });
```

if you return `return ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Count"].ToString()` directly then in `success` of ajax you can get count just by `response.d`

Solution 2 is more readable and easier than solution 1.

if you want to show `count` in related div with class `count` then 
`$(".count").html(count);`

Comment: i know, but i use Sqlserver. Maybe my C # code is wrong, you can fix it.   
I want to use Jquery calling code C# Eg: $.ajax({ type: "POST" ... Not XML data ...Thank you

Comment: So see the solution 2, more easy , just by changing code little.

Comment: I want to show on data <div class="count"> </div>..How do you do it?

Comment: I tried. But it does not work. I add [WebMethod] , public static string GetCustomers() code C#. And code Jquery $(function () {
            $.ajax....

Comment: I guide you, I don't know what is the problem or exception, but you can see [this](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-WebMethod-PageMethod-using-AngularJS-AJAX-and-JSON-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx) also.

Comment: I put your code into the ascx page it was working on. Thank you very much! Wish you a good day :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
[WebMethod]
    //Remove static
    public string GetCustomers()
    {
        string query = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Devices";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DbConnect.ConnectStr))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    sda.Fill(ds);
                    //Return only count string
                    return ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Count"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Add jquery to aspx page:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        GetCustomers();
    });

    function GetCustomers() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "GetCustomers",
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                $(".count").html(response);
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Do not display data .count

Comment: i use ascx page, it work. thank you very much for help me. Have a good day
 :)